# sshd service down + remote console HP/CentOS 6

Tags: centos, ssh, hp, ilo

I have HP server running CentOS 6, where sshd service was unable to start after restarting it, so I lost access to the server via ssh.

iLO service is working but not the console, regardless through the GUI or ssh the iLO itself, so I am unable to bring the sshd service up again.

Restarting the server is not a good idea since it is physically far away with no on spot support available.

when starting `vsp` it show only as following:

```
Starting virtual serial port.
Press 'ESC (' to return to the CLI Session.
```

Is there command line script being used to show running services and taking them up/down ?

Answer (score 1):

The ILO has a web interface. You can use that to connect to the console.

You can also SSH to the ILO and run `textcons` to bring up a text console, depending on the CentOS run level and GUI situation.